# Finding a Laurent polynomial that behaves at a pole like a given function

Tags: polynomials

I need to find a polynomial $P$ such that $P(1/x)$ behaves like given function $f(x)$ at zero (their difference vanishes), even if $f(x)$ has a pole at $0$ or unknown order.

P.S. I need to find a general form for principal part of Laurent series of $\Gamma (n) (-\ln (q+1))^{-n}$

Comment: Have a look at Series. It is also able to compute Laurent expansions.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks. I already found the close form for the desired function.